# "Lying on couches is boring" vs. "Lying on couches are boring"

Tags: grammatical-number, linking-verbs

Using the example sentence in the title, would you use the plural linking verb "are" or singular linking verb "is"?

The same question can be applied to anything with the following format:

> (action verb ending with -ing) (prepositional phrase) (*singular or plural* linking verb) (adjective)

To take a step further, here are my reasoning for the two in the title.

> Lying <s>on couches</s> is boring.

And the other example:

> <s>Lying on</s> couches are boring.

Comment: The second option is ungrammatical.

Comment: *Laying ... is boring*.

Comment: What *I* would use? For starters, I would correct *laying* to *[lying](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/051402lielay.htm),* since the usage appears to be intransitive. That done, I would use the singular verb *is,* as agreeing in number with its subject, the gerund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option, "Lying on couches is boring", is correct. The word "lying" is used as a gerund here, meaning that although "lie" is a verb, "lying" is a noun. This is a singular noun, so saying "lying is boring" is just like saying "The book is boring" or "My cat is boring".

"On couches" is a prepositional phrase, modifying the gerund, so basically it's an adjective. It's like saying "The green book is boring", or "The book about fish is boring". In both cases, "green" and "about fish" are used as adjectives, and don't really directly affect the verb.

So it's "lying on couches is boring" because "lying" is singular, and you would still use "is" even if there was only one couch ("lying on the couch is boring"), as "on couches" only describes the noun/gerund.

Comment: Nice post, but *laying* is still a verb when it is a gerund. It is just the head of a clause, *laying on couches*, which is doing a job often done by noun phrases i.e. being a Subject. (Erm, and *on couches* is the Complement of the verb *lay*, it isn't a Modifier here ...)