# "Doing such stunts ARE punishable" or "Doing such stunts IS punishable"?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, ing

> 1. Doing such stunts **are** punishable.
> 2. Doing such stunts **is** punishable.

Should it be *is* or *are*?

There is a conflict. *Stunts are punishable* sounds right. However, I think whether  *is* or *are* should be used will not depend on a plural or singular form of the noun *stunts* here. It depends on something else.

Why do we need singular or plural verb agreement here?

Comment: See also [“Lying on couches is boring” vs. “Lying on couches are boring”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321389/lying-on-couches-is-boring-vs-lying-on-couches-are-boring)

Answer (score 5):

Analyze the sentence, substitute **such stunts** with **X**. See if it still makes sense:

> Doing X is punishable.

The punishment in this case is not for **such stunts** but rather the action of **doing** them. Therefore we can use "is" in this sentence.

We can expand the example with other actions:

> Running a hundred miles without any breaks is not smart.
>
> Taking on that many assignments is not a good idea.
>
> Carrying too many bottles filled with liquids is not allowed on international flights.
>
> Killing people or domesticated animals is a punishable offense.

Answer (score 4):

> Doing such stunts is punishable.

The example above has a clause as a Subject. We can parse it like this:

- [Doing such stunts] is punishable.

When the Subject of a sentence is a clause, we always see singular verb agreement:

- That she is not here yet **is** problematic.
- For her to do that **is** undesirable.

It does not matter if the clause has an expressed Subject or not:

- Eating babies **is** wrong
- To forgive **is** noble.

If we use plural verb forms when we have a clause as a Subject, the result will be ungrammatical:

- *That she is not here yet **are** problematic. (ungrammatical)
- *For her to do that **are** undesirable. (ungrammatical)
- *Eating babies **are** wrong. (ungrammatical)
- *To forgive **are** noble. (ungrammatical)

For this reason we need singular verb agreement in the Original Poster's sentence. Why? Because:

- *[Using plural verb forms with clausal Subjects] **are** ungrammatical. (ungrammatical)

Comment: How do you analyze “Showings of movies before noon are half-price.”

Comment: @Jim Any -*ing* word with an S on the end is a noun not a verb (a"deverbal" noun). Because they're nouns they can't take a direct object, and the 'object-like' phrase must appear in an *of*-preposition phrase. Such nouns can of course also have articles and so forth. For comparison with *-ing* nouns consider *-tion* ones. *celebrating the festivities* verus *celebration**s** **of** the festivities*. Of course, plural nouns most often take plural verb agrement! :-)