# Which one is correct? "Vaccinating children has become..." or "Vaccinating children have become..."

Tags: verb-agreement

I have a doubt about the following sentence.

"Vaccinating children has become increasingly popular these days."

According to my understanding children is plural so, this sentence suppose to be like this

Vaccinating children have become increasingly popular these days.

is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Each of the alternatives is grammatical, but actually means something different, so "correct" is moot. Both are strictly correct, but only one will mean what you think it should. What do you think the sentence should mean?

Comment: I've never seen a child actually in the act of vaccinating before...

Comment: No, it isn't correct. It is not the _children_ who have become popular, but the _practice of vaccination_.

Comment: Try getting rid of the word that is not really important to understand the sentence; what do you end up with? Do you end up with “Children have become increasingly popular” or “Vaccinating has become increasingly popular”? (Historically speaking, I’m fairly sure that children have always been quite popular; we’ve been having them for ages, at least.)

Comment: See also [“Doing such stunts ARE punishable”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397260/doing-such-stunts-are-punishab)

Answer (score 1):

In literature:

> Additionally, there is a growing body of research wherein nasal
>   **vaccination has become** increasingly popular.  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z36GjK1vABEC&lpg=PA225&dq=%22Vaccination%20has%20become%20increasingly%20popular%20%22&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q=%22Vaccination%20has%20become%20increasingly%20popular%20%22&f=false)

Thus, as in:

> Vaccinating (a gerund) children has become increasingly popular

is the grammatically correct form.

Comment: _Vaccinating_ is not really a noun here – if it were, it wouldn’t be able to take an object (_children_). Rather, it’s a gerund, which is a verbal form that has certain noun-like properties (such as the ability to be the head of a noun phrase), but retains certain verb-like properties as well (such as the ability to take objects).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet noted and so edited.