# Using *plural* allow(s) me to

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

I can not figure out what the correct usage of allow/allows is in this case.

> Using plural allow(s) me to...

Would "allow(s)" refer back to the plural and thus be "allow"? or does it refer back to the action of using the plural and thus be "allows"?

An example could be something like: "Using old recordings allow(s) me to relive memories."

Comment: _Using plural_ is a verb phrase, the remains of a gerund clause being used as the subject. Phrases and clauses used as nouns are always singular. So it's _allows_.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnLawler, even though it is a short answer, would you please add it as one, so that I can close the question as answered?

Comment: Side note: *using plural* doesn't make sense. Depending on context, it should either be *using* ***the*** *plural* or *using* ***a*** *plural*. But nobody just *uses plural*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Based on the example ("Using old recordings..."), I don't think Nicky was planning on using the literal sequence of words "using plural". The word "plural" in the title and quote block just seems to stand for a plural noun phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford I did indeed mean what Sumelic said. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (gerund) noun phrase 'using plural' is the subject and it is singular (because 'using' is singular and 'plural' is just the object of the gerund), so the verb would be 'allows'.  Note that 'plural' has no determiner, so it is either a non-count (mass) noun or an adjective of a zero noun.  Its an adjective because the mass noun would be 'plurality'.

Gerund phrases can be plural, by making the gerund (participle) plural:
"Spellings of palindromes allow reversal.", but 'usings' would be better changed to 'usages'.

Comment: Based on the example ("Using old recordings..."), I don't think Nicky was planning on using the literal sequence of words "using plural". The word "plural" in the title and quote block just seems to stand for a plural noun phrase.

Comment: @sumelic - you are quite right.  I fell in with the earlier comments.  If Nicky wants, I will change the answer, but it works as is (and 'recordings' might warrant more explaining: it has no affect on the agreement).

Comment: I think the question has already been answered on the linked page: [Making adult decisions “is” or “are” really not fun: Which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18815) There are also other relevant answers on the page [“Doing such stunts ARE punishable” or “Doing such stunts IS punishable”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397260/doing-such-stunts-are-punishable-or-doing-such-stunts-is-punishable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @sumelic - Yes, it was answered.  I missed the link.  If my glaucoma is causing problems, I'll try to conserve my interactions.  (Sorry to get real)